# First use of glossary entry with asterisk

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

My question seems easy : How put an asterisk at the end of all first use of glossaries occurrences in the text (or for exemple, put it in bold…) ? But only in my glossary, not in my acronyms.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{word}{name={word},description={def. 1}}
\newglossaryentry{other}{name={other},description={def. 2}}
\newacronym[option=description]{acr}{Acronym}{Complet}+

\begin{document}
First use of \gls{word} and second use : \gls{word}.\\
First use of \gls{other} and second use : \gls{other}.\\
First use of \gls{act} and second use : \gls{acr}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I want just this result :

> First use of word* and second use : word.
>
> First use of other* and second use : other.
>
> First use of Acronym (acr) and second use : acr.

It must exist a simple command, but I don't find in [the big `glossaries`  manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)…

My problem is that I'm not english speaker. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a fairly up-to-date version of `glossaries` for this to work. (I think at least v4.0. The current version is 4.09.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\newglossaryentry{word}{name={word},description={def. 1}}
\newglossaryentry{other}{name={other},description={def. 2}}
\newacronym[description=description]{acr}{Acronym}{Complete}

\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}

\begin{document}
First use of \gls{word} and second use : \gls{word}.\\
First use of \gls{other} and second use : \gls{other}.\\
First use of \gls{acr} and second use : \gls{acr}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This just overrides the format for the `main` glossary. It uses `\glsgenentryfmt` to use the generic format for displaying the entry and then checks if the entry has been used with `\ifglsused`. If it hasn't been used, it displays an asterisk. The above produces:

[image: Image of document]